# Writing to .properties file in java web application

Tags: java

I was trying to write a key value pair to a chat.properties file in java .My function to do so is something like this :

```
public void WritePropertiesFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = 
        new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\SharedCrpto1\\web\\chat.properties");
    Properties configProperty = new Properties();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    configProperty.load(in);    
    configProperty.setProperty("newKey", "newValue");
    in.close();
    OutputStream outt = new FileOutputStream(file); 
    configProperty.store(outt, "my data");
    outt.close();
}
```

But its not working and the data is not being entered in the file.Please help to resolve the problem.

Comment: You need to close the streams properly.

Comment: @Nambari its also not working.I edited the post

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: @azurefrog Did you run it?Is the properties file having newkey=newValue ?I am getting empty file everytime

Comment: @azurefrog Oh..I got the problem.But just tell me how i can remove these comments ? Like #my data
#Fri Apr 18 01:31:12 IST 2014

Comment: Yes and yes.  It generates a new line each time I run your code with a different key-value pair.

Comment: It's putting in the #my data comment because you told it to in your `store()` command.  If you pass in a null comment you won't get that.  You can't write a properties file without the timestamp as far as I know.

Comment: @azurefrog also how to delete any record from this file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MakeEntryInPropertyFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\SharedCrpto1\\web\\chat.properties");
        prop.setProperty("newKey", "newValue");
        prop.store(output, null);
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```